# azure release pipeline task run powershell as admin from on-prem agent?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Have an on-prem agent that is used when running a release pipeline.  On of my tasks is a powershell script that needs to stop a windows service, hence it needs admin rights.  The agent runs under an account that has admin rights so that has me wondering, how does one run a powershell script as an admin on an agent of a deployment group?

You have to elevate its permissions somehow, the same way as if you run a powershell command "run as administrator".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Start-Process` with `-Verb RunAs` to run command as administrator.

You can use sc.exe tool to stop service. Commands and parameters can be passed in `-ArgumentList` similar to below:

```
& Start-Process sc.exe -ArgumentList "stop servicename" -Verb RunAs
```

Or you can use it with PowerShell Stop-Service command to stop windows service

```
& Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "Stop-Service -Name servicename" -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 2):

The Azure DevOps agent was running under the Network Service account. I changed it to run under the Local System account and it was able to stop and start the service.

```
Stop-Service -Name "ServiceName"
Start-Service -Name "ServiceName"
```

[image: Local System]

Answer (score 1):

> How does one run a powershell script as an admin on an agent of a deployment group?

It is not supported simply elevating permissions to run PowerShell as an administrator.

You can use a built-in task called "PowerShell on target machines" instead, which need you to provide some machine details and admin credentials:

1. a comma separated list of machine IP addresses or FQDNs along with ports. Port is defaulted based on the selected protocol. Eg: dbserver.fabrikam.com,dbserver_int.fabrikam.com:5986,192.168.12.34:5986
2. The administrator's username and password.

Comment: After researching this a bit, I found that I can simply elevate executionpolicy to "unrestricted" for the locamachine level.  However, you can also do this supposedly for via a group policy, eg.  for the domain user assigned to the agent service on the target machine.

Answer (score 1):

[AzureAdmin](https://github.com/sofdigital/AzureAdmin)  will work perfectly for you. We got around the same thing not being able to use elevated Powershell commands by creating a light .Netcore Worker service with http request capability. Just make sure you install the service with admin privileges and You can send a **Invoke-RestMethod** command from a regular Powershell YML task and it will trigger your custom logic on the other end of the ASP controller. We use it to remove Appx packages before re-installing for our Unit tests. The repo is located at, [Here](https://github.com/sofdigital/AzureAdmin) Customize it however you'd like.