# Azure Data Factory Running Powershell script as Admin in Azure Batch pool

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I created a Powershell script that connects to Azure MSSQL MI and run 3 queries then export the results in an excel file with multiple spreadsheets. But in order to do so. I need to install the modules needed for the script to run. These installations need to **have admin access.**

I managed to do this by manually running the Powershell ISE as Admin then execute the ps1 file. Now I want to run this script using Azure Data Factory in which these are the steps I did.

1. Save the ps1 file in the Storage Account > Containers
2. Created a Batch Account and Pools
3. Created Data Factory Pipeline with Custom Activity that points to the Container

[image]

Here are the contents of the Powershell script ***( Note: In the first part before Install_modules occured that's what I've found to run this file as an ADMIN)***:

```
param([switch]$Elevated)

function Test-Admin {

    $currentUser = New-Object Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal $([Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())

    $currentUser.IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltinRole]::Administrator)

}

if ((Test-Admin) -eq $false)  {

    if ($elevated) {

        # tried to elevate, did not work, aborting

    } else {

        Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-noprofile -file "{0}" -elevated' -f ($myinvocation.MyCommand.Definition))

    }

    exit

}

'running with full privileges'

 
Install-Module sqlserver
Install-Module -Name ImportExcel
Install-Module SqlPs

$server = 'someserver'
$database = 'MyDB'
$user = 'user'
$pass = 'password'

$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=tcp:$server,1433;Initial Catalog=$database;`
Persist Security Info=False;Authentication=Active Directory Password;User ID=$user;Password=$pass;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;`
Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Connection Timeout=10;")


$SheetNames =  @("Front_Tab","Balance Trending","X01 YTD Data")
$Queries =  @("SELECT * FROM sys.databases","SELECT * FROM sys.tables", "SELECT * FROM sys.objects")

$conn.Open()

foreach ($sheet in $SheetNames)
{
    $cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Queries[$SheetNames.IndexOf($sheet)], $conn)

    $dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $dataadapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)

    [void]$dataadapter.fill($dataset)

    $dataset.Tables | Export-Excel \\somelocation\Queryresult.xlsx -WorksheetName $sheet

}

$conn.Close()

Write-Output "Executed Successfully"
```

After running the ADF Pipeline the it generates some error text file in the Jobs and there's no file in the specified Export-Excel location

```
   Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The specified service does not exist 
as an installed service.
At D:\batch\tasks\workitems\adfv2-adfbatchpool\job-1\f6db97e3-f919-448e-a279-c159defb2e57\wd\ADFFile.ps1:12 char:9
+         Start-Process powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList ('-nop ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcess 
   Command
```

I'm not sure how to approach this next since my goal about this is to **run the ps1 file inside the batch account or batch pool as an Administrator**.

Here are the links I've taken a look at:

[Run Powershell Script as Admin](https://superuser.com/questions/108207/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-as-administrator)

[Elevated Privileges](https://serverfault.com/questions/1050733/no-admin-elevated-privileges-in-powershell-on-azure-vm)

[Admin ON-PREM Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63815497/azure-release-pipeline-task-run-powershell-as-admin-from-on-prem-agent)

[Run Script as Admin Automatically](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/01/run-powershell-script-as-administrator-automatically.html)